# Is it worth it to start using iPhone SDK 3.0 features?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am an iPhone newbie just starting to develop a new iPhone app, and I am wondering if it is better to stick with the 2.2.1 SDK right now or should I actively use features of the 3.0 SDK to build the app?  Of course it needs to eventually run on both 3.0 and 2.2.1 devices, so I need to test it on both.  But the question is whether there are cool new things in the 3.0 SDK (Xcode and Interface Builder features) that makes it worth using even if I am targeting 2.2.1.  For example, I would need to avoid using anything that relies on new 3.0 APIs, but maybe there are still cool new widgets or something that work fine with the 2.2.1 APIs.  Is that the case or not?  I'm just trying to figure out where I put my focus... 3.0 or 2.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

All apps submitted to the AppStore now have to be 3.0 capable.  Luckily the iPhone market is pretty cutting edge and will get the updates.  If they are downloading apps, they are probably updating their OS.

If you are planning to launch your app immediately I would say go with 2.2.1 but if you are looking out greater than 3-6 months then go with 3.0 stuff.  There are lots of great things in 3.0 such as virtual goods, apis to control itunes music and other benefits.  If you app requires features of 3.0 just start developing for it now.  1.0-2.0 seemed to take about 3-6 months for people to update.

Answer (score 1):

Start using the new features but you can't release an app yet for 3.0.

In short, do both.  There is plenty of power in 2.2.1 to get your app out the door.  Then you can add enhanced features that will improve the experience as 3.0 is officially launched.

I would focus on 2.2.1 for now because that is the most important currently.  Make sure it works on OS 3.0 though.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 3.0 - it will be released in one week, and practically everyone will upgrade straight away.

Comment: Has that been the case historically?  People upgrade right away?  I won't be releasing this until September, so if 90% of people have upgraded by then, it's probably best to just jump into 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if I'm allowed to post external answers, but here's an ars techinca article on the subject:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/03/app-store-lessons-firmware-followup.ars

Comment: Many apps will use 3.0 features very soon, because of some very compelling new frameworks and of course the user features which developers want to use themselves.

Historically the upgrade rate has been very high (they will not say exactly but probably 70-8% in a few weeks)

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 3G owners get the OS update for free via iTunes and will probably upgrade almost immediately. iPod Touch users have to pay and the improvements aren't very compelling for iPod users. So there is likely to be a split in the audience for your app if you target 3.0 for a while at least. Eventually so many apps will come out needing 3.0 that Touch users will be forced to upgrade and then it's not such an issue.

Of course, if the 3.0 feature makes your app that much more compelling, go for it, but a lot of app concepts don't of course.

Answer (score 1):

Actually apps submitted to the store need to be 3.0 capable, but that doesn't mean they have to use 3.0 features not available in older versions.

I would actually suggest that you stick to features that will add to your application regardless of them being new to 3.0 or not, and not just add the "new 3.0" features because they are cool or new. Add what your application needs to be successful and nothing more. the less requirements your application has, the more potential customers you have.